# Help solving complex equation

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

$$(1 + \sqrt{3i} ) z^{4} = - 800$$

I tried doing this, but it feels wrong:
[image]

Edit: I also tried multiplying with the conjugate in step 2,
and then multiplying with the conjugate again to get 9 in the denominator. It didn't help.

What is the right approach for solving equations like these?

Comment: Could you please show the original source of the problem? The reason I'm asking: are you sure the factor on the left-hand side is $(1+\sqrt{3i})$, not $(1+\sqrt{3}i)$?

Comment: @zipirovich yes I'm sure, if the teacher didn't fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second step, try multiplying the right hand side by the complex conjugate of the denominator (divided by itself, so you're multiplying by $1$). You should be able to reduce it to a simplified $a + bi$ that you can take the 4th root of $z$ to solve.

Comment: Actually that didn't help

Comment: yeah double check the i is rooted cause the solution doesn't make for a pretty equation. Plugging into wolfram alpha results in $$z = ± (2 i \sqrt(5) (-(2 - 2 i)/(\sqrt(6) + (1 - i)))^{1/4})$$ Not sure if that is a typical answer for the context you are used to

Comment: that's just 2 of the roots. The other 2 are the same equation but without the leading $i$

Comment: probably just a typo then. Thank you